# How to get a list of unused SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

We have an SQL Server with a lot of tables. In an effort to clean up the server we are trying to find which tables are actually being used. We have a list of tables on the server and now we would like to create a list of tables being used by our code.

We are using C# in Visual Studio 2013. Is there a way to compile a list of unused tables using Visual Studio? Or a list of tables used int the code--then we could compare to our list of tables.

I noticed in the Data Model (.edmx), when you right click on the diagram field, then go to Update Model from Database, a list of Tables, Views, and Stored Procedures is displayed (in the Update Wizard). Unless I'm mistaken, this all the unused tables from our connected database. Is it possible to export this list somehow?

Comment: I'm looking for unused tables not empty tables.

Comment: If you already know what tables you're using explicitly (and have a list of them), can you not just query sysobjects and exclude your used tables? Everything returned would be the unused portion.

Comment: This depends a lot on how your DB is accessed. Is all the code in stored procedures? Do you have strings embedded in your application? Do you use an ORM for access? A combination of all 3? You can analyze your code, or you can stand up a profiler trace for a period of time and see what is actually hitting your tables over the course of a day or so. But there is not an easy surefire solution.

Comment: @Phoenix: All we have is a list of all the tables on the server--we would like to have a list of the used tables...

Comment: @BillGregg: We use both stored procedures and an ORM. Our plan is to find all tables being used by the ORM and all tables used by the stored procedures. Then compare that list to all tables in the database.

Comment: If your servers are up and running for a decent time, you could inspect the index stats DMV to see if you find any clustered indexes that haven't ever been used since the last reboot of the server. That's a pretty good indication that nothing is happening on that table (no scans, no inserts)

Comment: Yes but what about tables that are only used annually. I'm not sure when the last server reboot was...I'll check

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do two things:

Set up a SQL Server Audit on the table(s) to see if any program does anything against the table, especially selects (which triggers cannot watch for). You may have to run this for a year to really be sure that its totally unused.

Run sp_depends or better use sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities (table_name, 'OBJECT') which will search through the entire database to see if any objects refers to this table.

exec sp_msforeachtable 'SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities (''?'', ''OBJECT'');'